# WEBPACK ERROR: When I do npm start, I am getting "Invalid number of parameters" Error

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-start, webpack.config.js

Very new to webpack.

I am obviously doing something wrong or doing something wrong. But No what that is.

In my package.json, under `scripts`, I have defined my own scripts which I would want to run for my project.

In `build`, I am just copying content from src to dist.

Below are the codes for `webpack.config.js` and `package.json`

Operating Sys: Windows 10

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react-project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && xcopy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && xcopy src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Nauman Tanwir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.7"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
            }
        }]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

[image]

Comment: I solved it changing `scripts` in `packgage.json` and modifying my `webpack.config.js`

Comment: I've rollbacked your last edit: please find your solution in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52158689/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own, thank you.